# How to create a menu at the bottom of a metro window in WPF

Tags: wpf, menu, mahapps.metro

I want to create a menu at the bottom of a metro window. How should I do it?

Attached image of what I am looking for. Gray area at bottom, over which will have buttons and click of button, popup will be shown with options.

Please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the vertical alignment of menu to bottom

e.g. :

```
  <Menu Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="86,0,0,0" Name="Menu1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Width="334">
        <MenuItem Header=" My"/>
        <MenuItem Header=" My option 2"/>
        <MenuItem Header=" My option 3"/>
    </Menu>
```